# redirect calls to $.fadeIn() to $.show()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single page application that's very CSS3 and graphic intensive, with lots of box-shadows and elements that move. I'm running on a pretty high-end laptop so it's no problem but when I put my laptop on energy saving mode, the processor slows down and the page sometimes becomes jerky, especially when fading elements in and out.

I think on tablets and other mobile devices, this will be a problem as well. I know I can use a global boolean flag and do something like this throughout my code:

```
if (SlowComputer) {
  $('#SomeID').show();
} else {
  $('#SomeID').fadeIn(800);
}
```

But is there a way to automatically redirect calls to `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` to calls to `show()` and `hide()` respectively?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to handle this would be to just turn off animations in that case.

```
jQuery.fx.off = true
```

It effectively sets the duration to 0 for all animations.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Edit:
Better Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fx.off/

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an interface "above" jquery? That can handle the if. And you can use your interface methods in your code - so do not have to take care about what happens exactly behind the scenes anymore...